# Replace the useless characters in dataset to clean it using python in Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I have a doubt that whenever I try to replace the `?` in the given dataset with `NaN`, I write the following piece of code in python using Numpy(`np` here) library provided by python

```
dataset = pd.read_excel("D:\Gursimran\AIML\Datasets\AdultIncomeData.xlsx")
dataset.replace('?', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

when i run this code, it shows no error but when I try to see the changes in dataset by :

```
dataset.head(10)
```

Then, I can see the `?` in my dataset again. These `?` are not replacing. Can anyone tell me that what I am missing?

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Hows your dataset look ?In which column you want to replace give some more information

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a few lines of the dataframe, to show how it is formatted, and more information about the output you want. This can help us help you!

Comment: @DapperDuck I have added the picture of my dataset. This is the sample as the whole dataset is quite big and has about 40000 rows.

Comment: @SimranKaur Thanks for the update, I'll take a look!

Comment: @DapperDuck hey, did you find any solution

Comment: I downloaded your dataset and @helder 's answer worked, so I didn't add another answer. However, I see your comment, and I feel I might have gotten the dataset from a different source. If you could link to where you found the dataset, I can take a look!

Comment: @DapperDuck You can browse to this link - http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/ and then download the "adult.data" dataset. Do let me know if the code works for you. I will be very thankful.

Comment: That is the dataset I used for my testing and helder's answer worked for me!

Comment: Perhaps set the inplace parameter as false

Comment: @Simran Kaur: How did you convert the CSV file "adult.data" to an Excel file "AdultIncomeData.xlsx"? (`pd.read_excel` can't be used with the CSV file directly, so I suppose there is some transformation being made?)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the some/all of the question marks are surrounded by some invisible characters such as white-space, tabulation or newlines. For example, consider the following sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [19, 28, 41, 30],
    'workclass': ['?', 'Private', 'Self-emp-inc', '   ?'],
    'occupation': ['Sales', '?', '?    ', 'Tech-support']
})
```

If we use `print(dataset)`, we see this:

```
   age     workclass    occupation
0   19             ?         Sales
1   28       Private             ?
2   41  Self-emp-inc         ?    
3   30             ?  Tech-support
```

If we look closely to the data printed, we might notice that in the question mark on third line is not alone, given that it is not aligned to the right of the occupation column. However, the question mark on fourth row seems to be alone, but this is not the case. Consequently, when replacing a single question mark as in

```
print(dataset.replace('?', np.NaN))
```

Only the ones in first and second rows are fixed:

```
   age     workclass    occupation
0   19           NaN         Sales
1   28       Private           NaN
2   41  Self-emp-inc         ?    
3   30             ?  Tech-support
```

This can be fixed e.g. by replacing also whitespaces. We could use a regular expression as in

```
print(dataset.replace('\\s*\?\\s*', np.NaN, regex=True))
```

and the result will be:

```
   age     workclass    occupation
0   19           NaN         Sales
1   28       Private           NaN
2   41  Self-emp-inc           NaN
3   30           NaN  Tech-support
```

Comment: This is good when we have spaces around the chracters but i don't have the spaces around the characters in my dataset and hence, this solution is not working for me. My problem is that the characters are not replacing even when they don't have any spaces around them.